# Retain multi-select list box items after ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view model which renders **N** number of listboxes in partial view.  Each list box has a unique ID which is called **PartID**. These listboxes allow users to multi-select list items.

What I am trying to do is before the ajax request is made, see if there are any listboxes present and store the respective listbox selected items indexes. If the same litsbox is rendered again then retain its previous selected items and pre-select on the success function of the ajax request.

These listboxes are fetched via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: serviceListPartsUrl,
                    cache: false,
                    datatype: "html",
                    data: { ServiceEntryID: $("#ServiceEntryID").val(), Parts: partTextArea },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#inputParts").html(result);
                    }
                });
```

**View Model**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RunLog.Domain.Entities;

namespace RunLog.WebUI.Models
{
    public class ServiceEntryListPartsViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<ServiceEntryPartDisplay> Parts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
<tr>
    <td>@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", Model.PartDescription)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PartDescription)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ServiceTypes, new MultiSelectList(RunLog.Domain.Lists.GlobalList.PartsServiceTypes(), "ID", "Name"), new { style = "width: 200px; height: 80px;", id =  @Model.PartID, name = "listbox" })
    </td>
    <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { style = "width: 200px; height: 80px;" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

**Controller Action**

```
  [HttpPost]
            //[OutputCacheAttribute(NoStore=true,Duration=0,VaryByParam="*")]
            public ViewResult ListParts(string ServiceEntryID, string Parts)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(ServiceEntryID);

                ServiceEntryListPartsViewModel viewModel = new ServiceEntryListPartsViewModel();

                List<ServiceEntryPartDisplay> parts = new List<ServiceEntryPartDisplay>();

                if (Parts.Length > 0)
                {
                    var partsServiceTypeResults = from rec in db.ServiceEntryPart
                                                  join ec in db.Part on rec.PartID equals ec.ID
                                                  where (rec.ServiceEntryID.Equals(id) && ec.Active == true)
                                                  orderby rec.ServiceEntryID
                                                  select new ServiceEntryPartDisplay()
                                                  {
                                                      ServiceEntryID = rec.ServiceEntryID,
                                                      PartID = rec.PartID,
                                                      PartDescription = ec.PartDescription,
                                                      ServiceTypeIDs = rec.ServiceTypeIDs,
                                                      Comment = rec.Comment
                                                  };


                    string[] splitData = Parts.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    foreach (string split in splitData)
                    {
                        ServiceEntryPartDisplay part = new ServiceEntryPartDisplay();

                        part.PartDescription = split;

                        part.PartID = Convert.ToInt32(split);
                        part.PartDescription = string.Format("{0} ~ {1}", split, (from pp in db.Part where pp.ID.Equals(part.PartID) select pp.PartDescription).FirstOrDefault());

                        var results = (from pp in partsServiceTypeResults where pp.PartID.Equals(part.PartID) select new { pp.ServiceTypeIDs, pp.Comment }).FirstOrDefault();

                        if (results != null)
                        {
                            part.Comment = results.Comment;
                            part.ServiceTypes = Domain.Lists.GlobalList.GetPartsServiceTypes(results.ServiceTypeIDs);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            part.Comment = "";
                            part.ServiceTypes = new List<Domain.Lists.PartsServiceType>();
                        }

                        parts.Add(part);
                    }

                }

                viewModel.Parts = parts;

                return View(viewModel);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify the way you're doing it.  Why not pass to your Controller a collection of a custom `ViewModel` that contains, say, `ServiceTypeID` and the currently selected Parts `ID`.  Withi that, you can properly generate the partial view with the correct items **already selected**.  You can do this trickery with javascript clientside, but I'd say take advantage of the tools you have.  Post all the necessary data back to the server and let MVC do its thing to help set up the view in the correct state.